# What is wrong with my script?

Tags: php, ajax

I don't see any errors in Firebug, and I can't figure out what's wrong with the AJAX.

PHP:

```
<?php


$subject = $_POST['subject'];

echo $subject;



?>
```

Javascript

```
  <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */ 

    function ajax() {


        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();           
        } else {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("result_div").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","message.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        return false;
    }

    /* ]]> */ 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result_div"></div>
<form action="" onsubmit="return ajax();">

    <select name="teest">
        <option value="hi">hi</option>
    </select><br />

    <input type="text" name="subject"> <br />
            <input type="submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: More specifically, jQuery serialize will build the submit data for you (http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) as well as make it much easier to submit the request (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) - as simple as $.post("message.php", $("#testform").serialize()); if your form had the id of "testForm".  Left to you to add setting the div value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not `POST`ing anything. When using ajax forms are *not* handled automatically for you.

Comment: Is it more ideal to use get or post?

Comment: Nothing is posted because xmlhttp.send(); is empty.  xmlhttp.send('subject=hello'); should set the div value to hello.